# Deploy javascript based azure function app through funcpack folder

Tags: javascript, azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-cli

We have Javascript based azure function app and we currently publish by running funcpack command and then deploy using azure function extension's GUI based commands - select subscription, select the FA and confirm deployment.

How to deploy the FA that is defined in the funcpack folder, through azure cli commands ?
OR how to deploy using powershell commands ?

Answer (score 0):

> How to deploy the FA that is defined in the funcpack folder, through azure cli commands ? OR how to deploy using powershell commands ?

According to [azure-functions-pack](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-pack)
, `funcpack command` has been replaced with [`Run From Package`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package).

- To enable your function app to run from a package, add a [`WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package#enable-functions-to-run-from-a-package) setting to your function app settings.

**CLI:**

```
az functionapp config appsettings set --name MyFunctionApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup --settings "AzureWebJobsStorage=$storageConnectionString"
```

**PowerShell:**

```
Update-AzFunctionAppSetting -Name MyAppName -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroupName -AppSetting @{"Name1" = "Value1"}
```